# Extra p elements created when calling the_field() or get_content() from within p tags

Tags: wordpress

"philosophy_text" is a `textarea` field created with the `ACF plugin` (Advanced Custom Fields). When displaying this field using the_field() from within p tags, the resulting markup is messed up with two extra p elements created out of the blue. Unfortunately this does not happen only with this particular plugin. I encountered this annoying problem with default `WordPress` function the_content() many times in the past:

My code:

```
<p class="philosophy__story">
    <?php if (get_field('philosophy_text')) the_field('philosophy_text'); ?>
</p>
```

The resulting markup:

```
<p class="philosophy__story"></p>
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Some more text that make sense for us to have, short not to much though.</p>
<p></p>
```

Is it a WordPress bug? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Custom Fields' `textarea` field has a setting for how to treat rendering new lines. By default, that setting is set to wrap the content in `<p>` tags.

You can change that to either print out `<br>` tags for newlines, don't do anything with newlines, or you can just remove your wrapping `<p>` element in your PHP code, and allow ACF to do it for you.

[image: ACF Setting]

Comment: I understand but as you can see in the resulting markup, the field's content doesn't simply get wrapped in a p element. It actually interferes and modify the parent p element, closing it: <p class="philosophy__story"></p> before proceeding with displaying the field content. That's different (and more "buggy") from your description (which sounds normal).

Comment: You're getting that from the Chrome Inspector? Try viewing source – you'll see that it's being outputted as expected. Nested paragraph tags isn't allowed by W3 spec, so Chrome autocloses it.

Comment: You're right! Why Chrome doesn't display the right information here?

Answer (score 0):

**edit** For textarea fields, @leland's answer is the correct one.  I'll leave this around in case someone is looking for the answer for other fields.

It's actually a feature, not a bug.  However, you can disable this feature if you don't like it.

Outside of ACF, this would be done via:

```
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

But ACF uses a custom filter called ‘acf_the_content’, so try this in your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
```

This answer was copied almost in its entirety from support for ACF

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/removing-paragraph-tags-from-wysiwyg-fields/

Comment: Small note: your ACF link is in reference to WYSIWYG fields – OP is referring to textarea fields.

Comment: Good catch.  I upvoted your answer since it is the better solution for OPs actual problem and leave mine in case someone has the other issue.

Comment: @vlasits as I commented to Leland, the field's content doesn't simply get wrapped in a p element. That would be perfectly fine by me! Instead, it interferes and modify the parent p element, closing it (<p class="philosophy__story"></p>) before displaying the field content. In other words it messes everything up, rather than simply wrapping something. Your description sounds normal, the actual behavior I'm witnessing feels definitely abnormal. There's simply no reason why the parent container should be affected in a any way.